# Does RabbitMQ have the inbuilt code to call an exe file

Tags: rabbitmq

I wanted to know if RabbitMQ has any built capabilities to call an external exe once its message queue get populated. I understand that we can implement task queues/worker queues in rabbitmq but it has to be done by writing an external application(say in java like they have mentioned in tuttorials http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html) . Please help me out with this

Adding to my previous question :

I have decided to write an application that will run an exe . But i dont want the application that i write to poll my queue. Instead i want my rabbitmq to trigger my application whenever there is a new message by sending a job to process. Can i do this? how can i add jobs to the queues?

Comment: What do you mean by 'inbuilt'?  What are you trying to achieve?  Some context would help here.

Comment: How would you imaging interacting with this code?  Are you looking for a way to just add the exe somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably going to have to write your own consumer. The question is what is sending the messages in the first place and what is the format o the message and do you need that data.

Python is probably the best choice for this task.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to avoid having an 'external application'.  And from what I gather, that means avoiding having to write a consumer.

Comment: Well I am pretty sure rabbit does not have a message to executable arguments tool. The message could be in any format. If he doesn't want another exe he can write a rabbitmq erlang plugin.

Comment: @davin@adam Davin is right. I wasnt looking at writing and external app to trigger my exe. So writing a plugin is the only answer? to elaborate the issue that i am facing so that @davin's prev questions are ans: my queue is getting populated with some messages. Right now i have written an external java app that will fetch the message and run the exe. I was looking at eliminating this java app and was hoping that message queuing systems(any message queuing) will provide me with this capability..

Comment: @davin@adam i was assuming that java code examples provided in the tutuorial was something that rabbitmq has provided

Comment: @shiva just realize by doing this you're breaking the decoupling functionality that RabbitMQ provides. A Consumer can be any language so you're not bound to Java. My question is why do you want this functionality? what benefit does it offer?